# mat-icon right padding? Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-icon

Angular Material Icons:

I have a **mat-icon** that I want to be beside the text. Nothing I do will reduce the space between the icon and the text though.

[image]

Based on this HTML :

```
      <span>
        <mat-icon [inline]="true" style="display:inline;">locked</mat-icon>
        <span AMELIA SMITH</span>
      </span>
```

Comment: Did my answer solved your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the inline and add custom css to align the text, current values are not accurate but you could change them

in CSS:

```
mat-icon {
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.a {
  padding-top:8px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

or only

```
mat-icon {
  vertical-align:text-bottom;
}
```

and in html:

```
<span>
  <mat-icon >locked</mat-icon>
  <span class="a"> AMELIA SMITH</span>
</span>
```